# Is it possible to change an installed application from a specific user to all users?

Tags: installation, python, multiple-users

For example, when installing python - I had the option to select all users during the installation but did not choose the option.

If I wanted to change the installation such that the program would be available for all users, could I do it without deletion and re-installation?

P.S. I'm running Windows 10~

Comment: For the apps I use (mostly not all purchased) the app must have the option. If it has the option you need to uninstall, restart and install with the new option.

Comment: There is a decent chance you can simply copy (or move) the shortcuts folder. Sometimes (but not always!) the difference is nothing more than the location of the shortcuts folder in the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you choose whether to install an app for 'Just Me' Vs 'All Users', that determines whether the app will be installed to Program Files/ProgramData vs the user's own AppData folder.

Therefore it's more than a matter of just giving all users access to a program, but rather the installation location and file permissions are different. So unless the installer has a feature where if you re-run it, it give some kind of option to move the installation or something, it is unlikely.